# Why does Stokes theorem apply to this situation?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I'm thinking Green's theorem or stokes theorem, but I don't know. It has been driving me crazy all day. Help me out here! And if you don't want to help because you know it's homework, give me some hints please :'(

$\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (2xyz + \sin(x))\vec{i} + (x^2z)\vec{j} + (x^2y)\vec{k}$

$$\int_{c} F \cdot dr$$

With parametrization given by: $c(t) = (\cos^5(t),\sin^3(t),t^4)$

I was told that Stokes theorem confirms that the integral of this is zero but I'm not understanding why Stokes theorem applies or how to know to even use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\text{curl}\left(\vec{F}\right)=\text{det}\begin{pmatrix} \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ 2xyz +\text{sin}(x) & x^2z & x^2y\end{pmatrix}\,\,.$$
Stokes' theorem says that $$\int_C \vec{F} \cdot \text{d}\vec{r}=\int\int_S \text{curl}\left(\vec{F}\right) \cdot \text{d}\vec{S}$$
for a simple, closed boundary curve $C$ of a smooth surface $S$ (and any vector field $\vec{F}$). Observe that if $\text{curl}\left(\vec{F}\right) = \vec{0}$, then the integral is zero, regardless of the surface which $C=c(t)$ bounds. The most important part of Stokes' theorem to recognize that clarifies your confusion is that: **the surface $S$ can be any surface as long as its boundary curve is given by $C$**.

Answer (score 3):

Recall Stokes theorem is the following:

$$ \int_c F \cdot dr = \int_S ( \nabla \times F) \cdot dS $$

In this case we see that

$$ \nabla \times F = \vec{0}$$

Therefore we have that

$$ \int_c F \cdot dr = 0$$

Comment: But how do I know Stokes theorem can apply to this problem? I think that's my question. How do I know it's a simply connected and a boundary encloses a surface.

Comment: I would suggest adding this to your question. To be specific, your question is why is it that $$\int_S (\nabla \times F) \cdot \text{d}S = 0$$
or why is it that $$\nabla \times F = \vec{0}\,\,?$$

Comment: Or "why does Stoke's theorem apply to this situation"? @user121615

Comment: Can I use Stokes theorem for any 3d vector field and line integral? Maybe that's why I'm confused.

Comment: You can apply Stoke's theorem when $S$ is an oriented smooth surface that is bounded by a simple, closed, smooth boundary curve $C$ with positive orientation.  There are restrictions to applying the theorem, but it works for any vector field $F$. Your curve $C=c(t)$ meets these restrictions.

Comment: How can you tell though? Did you graph it or seen it before, or is there an analytical way? That's what's throwing me off, I think. I know you are right because this test is based purely on Stokes theorem and Green's theorem.

Comment: No, I have never graphed or seen what your $c(t)$ looks like: the thing is, it doesn't matter...as long as you know it's closed and smooth, you're good to go, which it is.  As I explained in my answer, the surface $S$ can be *any* surface, as long as it is bounded by $C$...in this case, we don't care what the surface would be, since the integral turns out to be zero regardless. @user121615

Comment: You could graph it to verify that it is smooth and closed, but I see it intuitively...$\text{sin}^m(t)$ and $\text{cos}^n(t)$ and $t^k$ are smooth for any $m,n,k \in \mathbb{N}$, and thus the vector formed with these as components must be smooth.  Additionally, the parametrization is a closed boundary, this just comes from intuition...there is an analytical way to show this, but it is too long to write, so graphing would probably be the best option in most cases until you become familiar with parametrizations. @user121615

Comment: @user121615 you can use this site: http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/parcur/

Comment: Gosh, you are freaking awesome. Thank you so much. I been looking for a graphing thing like that. I don't have my maple anymore.